# An ubiquitous pattern of questions

Tags: lo.logic, soft-question, gr.group-theory, nt.number-theory, graph-theory

There is an ubiquitous pattern of questions concerning assumedly any kind of mathematical object or structure: groups, graphs, numbers, categories, and so on. It goes like this (informally):

> Can a class of objects or structures of a given kind *X* that is characterized by some "external condition" *Y* be defined by a condition *Z* in their respective "internal"
>   language, and if so: how?

Well-known examples ("external condition" **=** "internal condition"):

1. groups $G$ isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group on $G$ **=** all groups (*Cayley's theorem*)
2. graphs embeddable in the plane **=** graphs not containing a subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_5$  or $K_{3,3}$ (*Kuratowski's theorem*)
3. numbers *n* of trees on *k* labeled vertices **=** numbers *n = k*<sup>*k*-2</sup> for some *k* > 1 (*Cayley's theorem on trees*)
4. numbers *n* with only one group of order *n* **=** numbers *n = p<sub>1</sub> · p<sub>2</sub> ·  ... · p<sub>k</sub>* for some *k* > 0, where the *p<sub>i</sub>* are distinct primes and no *p<sub>j</sub>-1* is divisible by any *p<sub>i</sub>* (*cyclic numbers*, see [Sloane's A003277](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A003277))

Further examples from MO:

- [Which graphs are Cayley graphs?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14830/which-graphs-are-cayley-graphs)
- [Can we recognize when a category is
  equivalent to the category of models
  of a first order theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13155/can-we-recognize-when-a-category-is-equivalent-to-the-category-of-models-of-a-fir)
- [Can you determine whether a graph is
  the 1-skeleton of a polytope?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9255/can-you-determine-whether-a-graph-is-the-1-skeleton-of-a-polytope)

> **Question #1:** What's the proper way to
>   characterize this pattern of
>   questions? What's the common
>   context / rationale?

---

> **Question #2:** How is the introductory question to be
>   posed properly?

Comment: This is much too meta for MO.

Comment: I think this is way too philosophical and discussion-y to work on MO. Though you have made an admirable attempt at putting it in the form of a question, I don't think it's a question that "has an answer" (i.e. it's really bait for a discussion). I'd vote to close it as "not a real question", but I don't want to close unilaterally. If it acquires two or three other votes to close, then I'll vote to close too.

Comment: @Anton: Considering I just gave a reasonable answer. Would you consider not closing if I promise not to discuss the matter further?

Comment: @FGD: You know that your answer can still be voted up if the question is closed.  The only thing closing a question does is make it so other people can't answer it.

Comment: @fpqc: I did not know that. Thanks!

Comment: @François: I saw your answer just after I posted my comment, and I'm really impressed by it. I'm happy to leave the question open if we add the [lo.logic] tag. I'd still prefer that the question were written as a question about logic ... as is it's pretty philosophical.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are three sibling theorems of logic which guarantee that such characterizations are bound to happen.

- [The Craig Interpolation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_interpolation)
- [The Robinson Joint Consistency Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%27s_joint_consistency_theorem)
- [The Beth Definability Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_definability)

[The wikipedia entries need some work. I suggest you look up these theorems in a good logic book, for example Hodges's *Model Theory* or his more accessible *Shorter Model Theory*.]

I will focus on the Beth Definability Theorem, though the other two siblings lead to similar conclusions in slightly different contexts.

Suppose you have a first-order language L<sub>0</sub> and a larger language L. Let T be a theory in L and let φ(x) be a formula of the larger language L with the following property. Whenever A<sub>1</sub> and A<sub>2</sub> are two models of T which have the same universe A and the same interpretation for all parts of the small language L<sub>0</sub>, then A<sub>1</sub> ⊧ φ(a) iff A<sub>2</sub> ⊧ φ(a) for all a ∈ A. Beth's Definability Theorem says that there must be a formula φ<sub>0</sub>(x) of the smaller language L<sub>0</sub> such that T ⊦ ∀x(φ(x) ↔ φ<sub>0</sub>(x)).

The connection with your question is as follows. The base language L<sub>0</sub> is the 'internal' language of the structures you really care about, while the larger language L has some additional 'external' data. The theory T characterizes the structures with external data that you care about, and φ(x) is a property of such structures that you are interested in. If φ(x) is sufficiently independent of the external data, then φ(x) must be equivalent to an internal formula φ<sub>0</sub>(x).

Not all of the examples you give are easily cast into this formalism, but the basic flavor is the same. Unfortunately, the Beth Definability Theorem (and its proof) does not say much on how to find the internal formula φ<sub>0</sub>(x) but, at least, it says that the search will not be in vain.

Comment: Hm... Are any of the examples from the question easily cast into this formalism?

Comment: 1 & 3 are pretty straightforward. (Though not very interesting.)

Comment: Oh, I see now that 1 says "isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group on G" and not just "isomorphic to a subgroup of some symmetric group". I can see how to cast that first one into this formalism. But I couldn't see how to cast the latter.

Comment: No, wait, actually, I can't see how to cast the first one into this formalism; what I was thinking of doing doesn't work quite right. Could you perhaps illustrate exactly what T, L, phi, and phi_0 should be?

Comment: I had misread 3 when I wrote the above comment. However, 3 & 4 are trivially realized by taking L to be a suitable extension of arithmetic, but then the result is utterly trivial.

Comment: Well, suppose T is just the theory of a group and phi is the proposition stating that the action is faithful. Then we won't satisfy the condition that models which agree on the group structure also automatically agree on phi.

Alternatively, T could be the theory of groups + the condition that the action is faithful. Then all we get out of this is in the end is that T proves that phi is equivalent to phi_0; i.e., that the two are equivalent for all groups with a faithful action; but this tells us nothing about what kinds of groups actually have faithful actions.

Sorry, I still need help.

Comment: Hm, I appear to have replied to a comment that no longer exists. It was something about how to cast 1 (Cayley's theorem) into this formalism. Have you retracted it because you no longer believe this can be done in a non-trivial way (using Beth's definability theorem to obtain a non-trivial result about groups which substantially anticipates Cayley's theorem) or have you retracted it for some other reason? If the latter, I would still appreciate help seeing the details written out, as I was not able to understand from your previous comment quite what everything should be, as noted above.

Comment: I retracted my comment because it didn't work, as you observed. (I didn't see you had replied when I deleted it.) You can do a similar trick as with 3 & 4, but again the result is completely trivial. In order to apply Beth's Theorem, you really want phi(x) to say something about the objects of interest. In this case, x should be a group, which makes the process trivial again.

Comment: Ah, alright. Just curious. No worries on not seeing my reply when you deleted your comment; quite possibly, I was still in the middle of composing it.

Comment: I thought some more about how much of Cayley's Theorem you could get by general principles like the above. Robinson's Theorem comes closest, but the only conclusion I could get is that there are first order pure group theory sentences such that every group without a faithful action satisfies one of them and no permutation group satisfies any of them. This is not completely trivial assuming you're not aware of Cayley's Theorem. (The same reasoning applies perhaps less trivially to other representations of groups.)